# Extensibility and multi tenancy in an ASP.NET World

Tags: asp.net, architecture, multi-tenant

Imagine a multi tenant solution, running in an IIS web server, where you want to offer to your users/tenants the possibility of execute custom code (only for their tenant). Example: run a custom script before and after save a record.

How would you architect this? What are the available solutions nowadays?

Answer (score 1):

IMHO This is one of the must-haves in a typical SaaS Application.

A typical implementation will be to provide a highly configurable system where in the tenant's can plugin their own job / script on the occurrence of a CRUD or some other action on an Entity. I will provide a brief outline of this process

1. On every service, you can provide an end point with the necessary inputs that may be required for the pluggable code to act upon.
2. The end points will be designed such that it will identify your client, [the tenants] and then pick up the required custom script and then execute them.

Something that is like Policy Injection as part of the Enterprise Library but lacks the multi-tenancy part.

I happen to work with a Multi-Tenant SaaS framework named [TechCello](http://blog.techcello.com/2013/03/cello-framework-ver-4-2-released/) which has a couple of ways to accomplish this with ease via pre and post processors and eventing system that can be plugged to external web service calls.

Comment: According to your LinkedIn profile you work for TechCello. That doesn't make your answer invalid and I have not downvoted, but you should be transparent and say that you work for them.